# Download iOS SDK 3.1.2 and simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, ios-simulator

Where can I  download iOS SDK 3.1.2 and simulator as well? Maybe someone will upload 'em in web?

Comment: Sorry, out of luck (at least here)

Answer (score 0):

If you are a registered Apple developer, go to connect.apple.com, log in with your developer credentials, and you will see all the Apple assets available to you to download, including older versions of the developer tools. Not sure if Xcode 3.1.2 is still there, but it might be.

Comment: There are XCode installations without iOS SDK